# The issue with sharing a feature folder

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, architecture

In a UI solution, I have a "features" folder in my ReactJS solution holding a multitude of features.

What I would like to know is:

- Can a single feature be shared across multiple pages?
- if it can, then should there be a "shared" folder under the "features" folder to hold each feature that is shared across 2 or more pages? All non-shared features are in the root of the "features" folder.

I am using plain ReactJS, however, this question can be applied to any UI App architecture.

I have looked at a multitude of blogs on this area with no luck. Architecture